# Validar senha com confirmar senha

Tags: php, html, ajax, validação

Estou tentando validar minha senha mais preciso que seja idêntica ao campo de confirmar senha, estou validando em php e usando ajax para mostrar erro caso o valor do input esteja incorreto. Já tentei comparar usando === mais até agora nada, alguma sugestão?

html:

```
   <tr>
     <td><input type="password" id="senha" name="senha" placeholder="Senha" onBlur="Validate('senha', document.getElementById('senha').value);"><br><span id="campo_senha" class="error"></span></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td><input type="password" id="confirmsenha" name="confirmsenha" placeholder="Confirme sua senha" onBlur="Validate('confirmsenha', document.getElementById('confirmsenha').value);"><br><span id="campo_confirmsenha" class="error"></span></td>
   </tr>
```

JS/Ajax

```
    function Validate(field, value){

if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else if(window.ActiveXObject){
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");   
}

var urlget = "php/register.php?field="+field+"&value="+value;
var url = "php/register.php";
var params = "field="+field+"&value="+value;

xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xmlhttp.readyState === 1){
        document.getElementById('campo_' +field+ '').innerHTML = '<font color="green">Verificando...</font>';   
    }

    if(xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200){
        var resposta = xmlhttp.responseText;
        document.getElementById('campo_'+ field + '').innerHTML = resposta;
    }
};

xmlhttp.send(params);
}
```

PHP

```
    $error = array(
    "Campo deve ser preenchido.",
    "Somente 20 caracteres são permitidos.",
    "Somente letras e espaços são permitidas.",
    "Formato de e-mail inválido.",
    "Mínimo de 3 caracteres.",
    "Somente 30 caracteres são permitidos.",
    "Mínimo de 5 caracteres.",
    "Somente letras e números são permitidos.",
    "Senhas precisam ser idênticas."
);

$field = $_POST['field'];
$value = $_POST['value'];
$idfield = $_POST['id'];
$nome = "";
$sobrenome = "";
$email = "";
$senha = "";
$confirmsenha = "";

// Senha
if($field === "senha"){
    $senha = $value;
    if($senha === ""){
        echo $error[0]; 
    } else if(strlen($senha) > 20){
        echo $error[1]; 
    } else if(strlen($senha) < 5){
        echo $error[6]; 
    } else if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/", $senha)){
        echo $error[7]; 
    }
}

// Confirma senha
if($field === "confirmsenha"){
    $confirmsenha = $value;
    if($confirmsenha === ""){
        echo $error[0]; 
    } else if(strlen($confirmsenha) > 20){
        echo $error[1]; 
    } else if(strlen($confirmsenha) < 5){
        echo $error[6]; 
    } else if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/", $confirmsenha)){
        echo $error[7]; 
    } else if(!$confirmsenha == $senha){
        echo $error[8];
    }
}
```

Comment: A comparação parece está certa, porém a variavel `$senha` é `$senha = ''`, logo ele irá retornar erro se a senha for diferente de `` (nada), que é o mesmo erro do `$error[0]` que é acionado quando insere um dado vazio.

Comment: Entendi o que quis dizer, mas não sei como puxar o valor para $senha, por causa da função, obrigado.

Comment: Eu tenho uma dúvida, o que queres fazer não é comparar a senha com a confirmasenha?
Na tua linha de código apenas vejo se a senha e a confirmasenha está nos parâmetros por ti definidos.
Não terias assim algo do genero: if($senha===$confirmasenha)
{ echo "senhas corretas";
}
else
{ echo "senhas não coincidem";
}

Comment: não precisa dar essa volta toda. Apenas compare ambas no javascript... e quando submeter o formulário, faz a validação de todas as entradas normalmente, incluindo a senha e confirmação de senha

Comment: Uma pergunta: O problema não seria o fato de o php ser `server-side`, ou seja, pelo que eu entendi, você lançou os parâmetros para o php fazer a confirmação. só que o php já foi lido certo? da um `echo` em alguma variável do php e veja em que momento ele aparece ou se ele aparece.

Comment: o @Daniel Omine tem razão, melhor você fazer a análise antes de lançar para o php.